# Concatenation and contraposition laws in modified Stalnaker system

Tags: logic, nonclassical-logic

The first four axioms of *Stalnaker conditional logic*, which adds $\mapsto$, the *counterfactual conditional* symbol, to the operator symbols of classical logic, are

1. $A\mapsto A$
2. $(A\mapsto B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow B)$
3. $(\lnot A\mapsto A)\rightarrow (B\mapsto A)$
4. $((A\mapsto B)\land(B\mapsto A))\rightarrow((A\mapsto C)\leftrightarrow(B\mapsto C))$

The inference system uses two inference rules (together with the rules of classical logic for the truth-functional symbols, I think, although the text I am following -see below- explicitly tells nothing about that):

- $A\leftrightarrow B\vdash(C\mapsto A)\leftrightarrow(C\mapsto B) $
- $A_1\land\ldots\land A_n\rightarrow B\vdash (C\mapsto A_1)\land\ldots\land (C\mapsto A_n)\rightarrow(C\mapsto B)\quad\quad\quad(n\ge 0)$

I read -D. Palladino, C. Palladino, *Logiche non classiche*, 'non-classical logics', 2007, p. 122, for anybody having the book- that adding the following axiom$$(A\lor B\mapsto C)\leftrightarrow (A\mapsto C)\land (B\mapsto C)$$to the above rules and four axioms would make the the *contraposition law* $(\lnot A\mapsto\lnot B)\rightarrow(B\mapsto  A)$ and the *concatenation law* $(A\mapsto B)\rightarrow((B\mapsto C)\rightarrow(A\mapsto C))$ valid (which usually is not desired in conditional logic), but I am not able to prove it to myself. How can they be inferred? I heartily thank you for any answer!

***EDIT***: An answer to this question by a kind fellow MSE user, whom I thank very much, does exist, but presents **a problem**, as noticed both by the answerer and another user, since it does not use axiom $(A\lor B\mapsto C)\leftrightarrow (A\mapsto C)\land (B\mapsto C)$, in particular the $(A\lor B\mapsto C)\rightarrow (A\mapsto C)\land (B\mapsto C)$ part, which is **indispensable** to prove the concatenation and contraposition laws, which are not valid in absence of that axiom. Indeed, $(A\lor B\mapsto C)\rightarrow (A\mapsto C)\land (B\mapsto C)$ is usually left out of conditional logic systems, where the concatenation and contraposition laws are not desired.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. Please edit your question, so that it is clear what needs to be proved.

Comment: @LoMaPh Thank you for your comment! I have moved "how can they be inferred" nearer to the two propositions (which I had called "(un)desired propositions" because conditonal logic avoids axiom $(A\lor B\mapsto C)\leftrightarrow (A\mapsto C)\land (B\mapsto C)$ in order that they be not valid) whose validity I would like to understand in the described system.

Comment: The second rule doesn't look like a rule of inference.

Comment: Is the third axiom correct? I am reading this to mean if not A "whatevers" A then anything "whatevers" A.

Comment: @Jonny Yes, it is. It's analogous to the classical logic theorem $(\lnot A\rightarrow A)\rightarrow(B\rightarrow A)$, although the $\mapsto$ implication is not the same as the $\rightarrow$ implication in conditional logic. Thank you for the request of explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contraposition. Want to show $(\neg A\mapsto\neg B)\to(B\mapsto A)$.

1. Assume $(\neg A \mapsto \neg B) \land \neg(B \mapsto A)$, looking for contradiction.
2. By axiom 2, $\neg A \rightarrow \neg B$, or equivalently $A \lor \neg B$
3. New axiom letting $C = A$. $(A \lor B\mapsto A)\leftrightarrow (A \mapsto A)\land (B\mapsto A)$
4. By axiom 1, $(A \lor B\mapsto A)\leftrightarrow (B\mapsto A)$

If $A$ is true then $B$ is irrelevant on the left hand side and therefore $(B \mapsto A)$, a contradiction.

If $A$ is false, then $B$ must also be false by 2, and therefore $B = A$. So by axiom 1 $(B \mapsto A)$, a contradiction.

---

Concatenation. Want to show $(A\mapsto B)\rightarrow((B\mapsto C)\rightarrow(A\mapsto C))$

1. Assume $(A \mapsto B) \land \neg ((B \mapsto C) \rightarrow (A \mapsto C))$. Looking for contradiction.
2. Equivalently, $(A \mapsto B) \land (B \mapsto C) \land \neg(A \mapsto C)$.
3. New axiom $(A \lor B \mapsto C) \leftrightarrow (A \mapsto C) \land (B \mapsto C)$.

Thus it is sufficient to show that $(A \lor B \mapsto C)$.

If $B$ is true, we are done, so continue assuming $B$ is false.

4. Axiom 2 and step 2 gives us $A \rightarrow B$. Since $B$ is false, $A$ must also be false.

Since $(A \mapsto B)$ is true we gather that $(\bot \mapsto \bot)$ must be true.

If $C$ is false then $(A \lor B \mapsto C)$ is $(\bot \lor \bot \mapsto \bot)$ which is true and we are done.

If $C$ is true, note that $(B \mapsto C)$ is true, therefore $(\bot \mapsto \top)$ is true, and therefore $(A \lor B \mapsto C)$ is true and we are done.

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide It feels a little funky, but I think the concatentation proof is good. Since we are within an assumption, we can 'prove' things about this new counterfactual conditional operator that may or may not actually be true outside of the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

### Contraposition: $(\neg A\mapsto\neg B)\to(B\mapsto A)$

We start with the tautology: $(B\to A)\to(B\to A)$.

Contraposition of the premise yields: $(\neg A\to\neg B)\to(B\to A)$.

Contraposition of the whole formula yields: $\neg(B\to A)\to\neg(\neg A\to\neg B)$.

By the contrapositive of axiom 2, this is equivalent to: $\neg(B\mapsto A)\to\neg(\neg A\mapsto\neg B)$.

Finally, by contraposition of the whole formula: $(\neg A\mapsto\neg B)\to(B\mapsto A)$.

---

### Concatenation: $(A\mapsto B)\to((B\mapsto C)\to(A\mapsto C))$

We start with the tautology: $(A\to B)\to((B\to C)\to(A\to C))$.

Contraposition yields: $\neg((B\to C)\to(A\to C))\to\neg(A\to B)$.

Distributing the negation into the implication: $((B\to C)\land\neg(A\to C))\to\neg(A\to B)$.

By the contrapositive of axiom 2, this is equivalent to: $((B\to C)\land\neg(A\mapsto C))\to\neg(A\mapsto B)$.

Extraction of the negation gives: $\neg(\neg(B\to C)\lor(A\mapsto C))\to\neg(A\mapsto B)$.

By the contrapositive of axiom 2, this is equivalent to: $\neg(\neg(B\mapsto C)\lor(A\mapsto C))\to\neg(A\mapsto B)$.

Rewriting the premise as an implication: $\neg((B\mapsto C)\to(A\mapsto C))\to\neg(A\mapsto B)$.

Finally, contraposition yields: $(A\mapsto B)\to((B\mapsto C)\to(A\mapsto C))$.

Comment: Forgive me: I cannot understand where you use $(A\lor B\mapsto C)\rightarrow (A\mapsto C)\land (B\mapsto C)$, which would be necessary to prove the two laws, according to the book. Interestingly, conditional logics usually avoids this axiom precisely in order to avoid such laws. $\infty$ thanks!!!!!

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide I'm not sure this derivation is even valid, to be honest. It does indeed seem strange that I didn't use this fifth axiom, so I must have made a mistake somewhere. As always, the best thing would be to ask [Mauro Allegranza](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/108274/mauro-allegranza) to be kind enough to check.

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide The problem is where he uses countrapositive of Axiom 2 (line 4 in both proofs). He uses $A\rightarrow B$, $A\rightarrow A'$, $B\rightarrow B'$ to derive $A'\rightarrow B'$, which is not valid. It could be valid if axiom 2 was $(A\mapsto B)\leftrightarrow(A\rightarrow B)$, but it isn't.

Comment: @LoMaPh Thank you too!